# ToolTip for Table cell ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have created a dynamic table using below code.It is only a part of my code.

```
if (i >= startNo && i <= endNo) {
        panelName.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td style=background-color:lightblue; >&nbsp;</td>"));
} else {

        panelName.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>&nbsp;</td>"));
}
```

I need to show a popup/tooltip message if the color is lightblue. Could you please help me out to figure this out?

[Output of the current program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnZr5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `title` property of the `td` like folloiwng.

```
panelName.Controls.Add(
new LiteralControl("<td title='some title' style=background-color:lightblue; >&nbsp;</td>"));
```

To set some dynamic value from server, you can try like following.

```
  string someToolTip = "Got from DB";
  panelName.Controls.Add(
 new LiteralControl("<td title='" someToolTip  + "' " +  "style=background-color:lightblue; >&nbsp;</td>"));
```

Comment: Thanks,It worked. Is it possible to bind some data from database to show

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check. Conciser accepting the answer if it resolved your query.

Comment: Thank you.is it possible to parse a table or some gridview or something like that?

Comment: something like thishttps://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238678/Using-The-JQuery-Tooltip-Plugin-in-a-GridView

Comment: Definitely it's doable, but you need to prepare the data from server side, which should be shown  on mouse over. You attach the data for each cell which needs to be shown from server side, and associate it with tool tip using any plugin. Better you start implementing it and ask appropriate question if you get stuck anywhere

Comment: great.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me out to add colspan to this rows ?